# find = strchr(st, '\n'); replaced with *find = '\0';

Tags: c, strchr

I read a snippet of code from *C Primer Plus*, and tried hard to understand `*find = '\0';`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *s_gets(char *st, int n);

struct book {
    char title[40];
    char author[40];
    float value;
}

int main(void) {
    ...
}

char *s_gets(char *st, int n) {
    char *ret_val;
    char *find;

    ret_val = fgets(st, n, stdin);
    if (ret_val) {
        find = strchr(st, '\n'); //look for newline
        if (find)                // if address is not null
            *find = '\0';        //place a null character there
        else
            while (getchar() != '\n')
                continue;  //dispose rest of line
    }
    return ret_val;
}
```

For what purpose should `find = strchr(st, '\n');` be followed by `*find = '\0';`

I searched `strchr` but found it an odd name although could get idea about it's function. Does the name `strchr` come from `stringcharacter`?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html , https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strchr.htm .. ? Search harder: "[strchr] searches for the first occurrence of the character [..] in the string [..]"

Comment: It zaps the newline that was read by `fgets()` and included in the result string, if there is indeed a newline in the string.  An alternative, more compact, notation is `s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = '\0';` which is written without any conditional code visible.  (If there's no newline, the null byte overwrites the existing null byte.)  The overall objective seems to be to make `s_gets()` behave more like an [antique, dangerous and no longer standard function, `gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/), which removes the newline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code using `find = strchr(s, '\n')` and what follows zaps the newline that was read by `fgets()` and included in the result string, if there is indeed a newline in the string. Often, you can use an alternative, more compact, notation:

```
s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = '\0';
```

which is written without any conditional code visible. (If there's no newline, the null byte overwrites the existing null byte.)

The overall objective seems to be to make `s_gets()` behave more like an [antique, dangerous and no longer standard function, `gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/), which reads up to and including a newline, but does not include the newline in the result.  The `gets()` function has other design flaws which make it a function to be forgotten — never use it!

The code shown also detects when no newline was read and then goes into a dangerous loop to read the rest of the line.  The loop should be:

```
else
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        ;
}
```

It is important to detect EOF; not all files end with a newline.  It is also important to detect EOF reliably, which means this code has to use `int c` (whereas the original flawed loop could avoid using a variable like `c`).  If this code carelessly used `char c` instead of `int c`, it could either fail to detect EOF altogether (if plain `char` is an unsigned type) or it could give a false positive for EOF when the data being read contains a byte with value 0xFF (if plain `char` is a signed type).

Note that using `strcspn()` directly as shown is not an option in this code because then you can't detect whether there was a newline in the data; you merely know there is no newline in the data after the call.  As [Antti Haapala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918959/antti-haapala) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52866332/find-strchrst-n-replaced-with-find-0/52866621?noredirect=1#comment92648310_52866621), you could capture the result of `strcspn()` and then decide whether a newline was found and therefore whether to read to the end of line (or end of file if there is no EOL before the EOF).

Comment: `strcspn` itself is an option but not if you assign to the location right away.

Comment: True — see amended final paragraph.  Thanks!